# Do leaflet labels support "\n" line-breaks?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

Trying to work on my mapping/data viz skills and do a quick bubble map of where my favorite bands and genres are from. So I have a column in my `data.frame` titled `bandnames` and I made it so that every band is separated by a line break using `\n`. I used `dplyr` for this:

```
dplyr::summarise(BandName = paste(BandName, collapse = "\n"))
```

This worked perfectly when I previewed the tooltip in the RStudio view function. Here's what I mean:

[image]

But in `leaflet`, there are no linebreaks:

[image]

Is there any way I can fix this without making each individual band its own row (which would complicate what I'm trying to do, since I want multiple band names for each location without having multiple bubbles)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep in mind leaflet renders html - so try something like

```
dplyr::summarise(BandName = paste(BandName, collapse = "<br>"))
```

and be sure to map it to popup (not label) in your leaflet call.

Or consider this example / it is built on mutate instead of summarise, the appropriate function will depend on the nature of your dataset. But the key part is using `<br>` as in HTML speak instead of `\n` as in R speak.

```
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%  # included with sf package
  st_transform(4326) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(label = paste(CNTY_ID, NAME, sep =  "<br>"))


leaflet(shape) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner") %>% 
  addPolygons(color = "blue",
              fillColor = "red",
              popup = ~label)
```

[image]